# com.mysql.jdbc You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: java

I'm getting this error in my Java code can anyone please help?

> com.mysql.jdbc You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ''id','username','email','password')VALUES(NULL,'INSERT INTO
>   user(\'id\',\'userna' at line 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 21
>   seconds)

Comment: What is the full SQL statement you're trying to execute?

Answer (score 1):

We can't see the entire query you are executing since you've only included this part:

```
'id','username','email','password')VALUES(NULL,'INSERT INTO user(\'id\',\'userna
```

From this, I'd guess that your problem is that your backslash-escaping should not be part of your actual query. Rather than this:

```
INSERT INTO user(\'id\',\'userna...
```

You want this:

```
INSERT INTO user('id','userna...
```

Without more information we can't tell if there are other issues with the query.